# Glassfish cannot find zeromq lib

Tags: glassfish, zeromq, classnotfoundexception, buildpath

I have a problem with glassfish4 when deploying my web app.

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/zeromq/ZMQ

I used eclipse and added /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar into BuildPath but i don't understand why this error displayed buy no err in my code.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, i found a solution. The jar file needs to be copied into $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/lib. So, it works.